# How do I add a inline ListFragment?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout like the following. It contains a few TextView and ImageView's. Below those I would like to add a ListFragment.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Name: "
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="Large Text" />
...
    <fragment android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        class="com.snot.bodyweightworkout.ExerciseListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Right now I'm adding my ListFragment using the code below. But I would like to add it as illustrated above. I'm guessing that I'll add it in the same way but what element should I use in my layout as a container?

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
if (fm.findFragmentById(android.R.id.content) == null) {
    ProgramListFragment list = new ProgramListFragment();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, list).commit();
}
```

Any suggestions on how to add it inline?

Comment: so just put the listfragment in your xml and not in code

Comment: I'm confused about how to do that. And in some cases I want to pass a paramenter to ProgramListFragment. Could you perhaps enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at the docs   http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Name: "
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:text="Large Text" />

<fragment android:name="com.example.news.ArticleListFragment"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

then when you want to get the fragment all you have to do is

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
ProgramListFragment plf = (ProgramListFragment)fm.findFragmentById(r.id.myfragment);
```

you can also substitute `FrameLayout` with fragment in your xml and just replace the view in the frame

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Name: "
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:text="Large Text" />

<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then you can basically do what you are doing already except instead of add you want `replace`

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
ProgramListFragment list = new ProgramListFragment();
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.list, list).commit();
```